# How do I store a set of queries inside PostgreSQL so I can easily run it again?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I want to save a set of queries (multiple SQL updates) as a single element that I can execute using pgAdmin3 (PostgreSQL 9.1).

I know that I can save single SELECTS as views but how about multiple UPDATE queries?

Example:

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE ...;
UPDATE ...;
COMMIT;
```

Update: What I looking for is a step-by-step guide of adding a stored procedure using the GUI, not running a SQL query that creates it.

So far, I encountered two problems with `"New function..."`: the return type is required and found that NULL is not acceptable, so tried `integer`. Also, set the type to `SQL` but I don't know what exactly to write inside the SQL tab, whatever I try the OK button is still disabled and the statusbar says: Please enter function source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you know or did you try stored procedure (well, stored-procedure-like functions) ?

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/plpgsql-structure.html

To call it

```
select <name of function>(<param1>, <param2>) as result;
```

Comment: Exactly, but how do I add it, run it and update it? Can you put basic example?

Comment: Let me explain: I tried to add a function, with language SQL, but it asks me about a return type.

Comment: Examples of creation are present in the page I gave (CREATE FUNCTION bla bla). If the function must return nothing, you can use CREATE FUNCTION blabla (parameters) RETURNS void as $$. To run it, see my edit. To update it : it must appear somewhere in treeview from pgAdmin, no (ain't got one here) ?

Comment: @sorin: Yes, pgAdmin shows functions in the object browser in treeview. Start by reading the [manual about creating functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html). Proceed with the link Raphael supplied. Be aware that SQL functions are different from plpgsql functions. You can use either for your job description so far.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the missing guide for a basic SQL stored procedure, one that does return 1.

- right click on Functions and choose **New Function...**
- complete `name` as `my_procedure`, `return type` as `integer`, `language` as `sql`
- select **Definition** tab and write `SELECT 1;`
- done

It would be nice to know if you can create queries that are returning nothing.

Comment: Thanks. Note - it looks like you mean to put `SELECT 1;` in the Code tab.